# Solution verification of some PDE with an additional condition

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

Provided a probability density $\rho:\mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R_+$ (as nice as possible), consider the PDE
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial_t p = \dfrac{\partial_{xx}p}{2\big(1+m(t)\big)^2} - \partial_x p, & \forall t>0, ~ x>0;\\
 m(t)  =\displaystyle \int\limits_0^{\infty}p(t,x)dx,& \forall t\ge 0;\\
p(0,x)=\rho(x),& \forall x\ge 0;\\
p(t,0)=0,&\forall t>0.
\end{cases}
$$
Set
$$
\Phi(z):=\int\limits_{-\infty}^z\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-r^2/2}dr,\quad \forall z\in\mathbb R.
$$
Define
$$
\color{blue}{p(s,y) := \int\limits_0^{\infty}\rho(x)g(0,x,s,y)dx + \int\limits_0^s \dot{m}(t)g(t,0,s,y)dt,} \label{1}\tag{$\ast$1} 
$$
where
$$
\begin{split}
g(t,x,s,y)&:=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi A_{t,s}}}\exp\left(-\frac{\big(y-x-(s-t)\big)^2}{2A_{t,s}}\right)\\
\mbox{with } A_{t,s}&:=\int\limits_t^s\frac{du}{\big(1+m(u)\big)^2}
\end{split}\quad \forall t\in [0,s),~ x,y\in\mathbb R,
$$
and $m$ satisfies

$$\color{blue}{m(s)=\int\limits_0^{\infty}\Phi\left(\frac{x+s}{\sqrt{A_{0,s}}}\right)\rho(x)dx + \int\limits_0^{s}\Phi\left(\frac{s-t}{\sqrt{A_{t,s}}}\right)\dot{m}(t)dt,~ \forall s\ge 0.}\label{2}\tag{$\ast$2}
$$

**Assuming the existence of $m$ s.t. \eqref{2} holds, can we verify $(p,m)$ is a solution to the above system?**

Any answer, comments and references are highly appreciated.

**P.S.** Let me describe in details where come from the above expressions in blue. First, integrating the PDE
$$
\int\limits_0^{\infty}\partial_t p(t,x)dx = \int\limits_0^{\infty} \frac{\partial_{xx}p(t,x)}{2\big(1+m(t)\big)^2}dx - \int\limits_0^{\infty} \partial_x p(t,x)dx
$$
together with the boundary condition $p(t,0)=0$, one has
$$
\dot{m}(t)=-\frac{\partial_{x}p(t,0)}{2\big(1+m(t)\big)^2},\quad \forall t>0.\label{3}\tag{$\star$}
$$
Next, using the fact
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial_t g = -\dfrac{\partial_{xx}g}{2\big(1+m(t)\big)^2} - \partial_x g, &\forall t\in [0,s), ~ x\in\mathbb R;\\
g(s,x)=\delta_y(x), &\forall x\in\mathbb R,
\end{cases}
$$
one may check

$$\partial_t(pg) + \partial_x(pg)- \frac{1}{2\big(1+m(t)\big)^2}\partial_x(\partial_x pg-\partial_x gp)=0,\quad \forall t\in (0,s),~ x>0.$$

Therefore, integrating this equality on $(0,s)\times (0,\infty)$ yields

$$\int_0^{\infty}\left(\int_0^s \partial_t(pg)dt\right)dx + \int_0^s \left( \int_0^{\infty}\partial_x(pg)dx\right)dt - \frac{1}{2\big(1+m(t)\big)^2}\int_0^s \left(\int_0^{\infty} \partial_x(\partial_x pg-\partial_x gp)dx\right)dt=0$$

and further by $p(0,\cdot)=\rho$ and $p(\cdot,0)=p(\cdot,\infty)=\partial_xp(\cdot,\infty)=0$

\begin{eqnarray}
0&=&\int_0^{\infty} \big(p(s,x)\delta_y(x)-\rho(x)g(0,x,s,y)\big)dx  + \frac{1}{2\big(1+m(t)\big)^2}\int_0^s \partial_x p(t,0)g(t,0,s,y) dt \\
&=&p(s,y)- \int_0^{\infty} \rho(x)g(0,x,s,y)dx  + \frac{1}{2\big(1+m(t)\big)^2}\int_0^s \partial_x p(t,0)g(t,0,s,y) dt \\
&=&p(s,y)- \int_0^{\infty} \rho(x)g(0,x,s,y)dx  -\int_0^s \dot{m}(t)g(t,0,s,y) dt\quad \quad \mbox{ in view of \eqref{3}}, \\
\end{eqnarray}

which gives \eqref{1}. Integrating \eqref{1} over $(0,\infty)$, one has

$$m(s)=\int_0^{\infty}\left(\int_0^{\infty}g(0,x,s,y)dy\right)\rho(x)dx  -\int_0^s \left(\int_0^{\infty}g(t,0,s,y)dy\right)\dot{m}(t) dt,$$

which gives \eqref{2}.

Comment: Is $\rho(0)=0$?

Comment: @Neymar It seems to correspond to the continuity condition on the boundary. We may assume it if needed